# QTDropbox: QDropbox - LNK1104: cannot open file Qt5Cored.dll

Tags: c++, qt, dllimport

I am trying to build Qt-Dropbox in c++ (Visual studio on windows). I get the following error: `cannot open file Qt5Cored.dll`.

I added the following links to my project:

In VC++ Directories:
[image: VC++ Directories]
In Linker => Input:
[image: Linker => Input]

Comment: If you install the VS Add-in, you don't need to worry about the Qt dependency settings, the add-in does all that for you when you select which modules to include.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `Additional Dependencies` you should put `.lib` files, not `.dll`. Dll files should be placed near the `.exe` file or in directory that included in `PATH` environment variable, so they can be found by loader.

You can find more info about it on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)